# Magento 1.7 image not uploading for products

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm trying to upload images for products in magento admin but could not do so. I have installed patched 7405v1.1 also but still problem exists. No errors are there in console or network tab.Product images are saving to tmp folder but not to media/catalog/product.